# Is the collection of probability measures tight?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $u_n$ probability measure on $\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R})$ with density $x \to \frac{1}{2n} 1_{[-n,n]}(x)$ w.r.t to lebesuge measure. Is the collection $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ tight?

First of all, $(u_n)$ is tight if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists M$ sucht that $\forall u_n$ $u_n([-M,M]) > 1-\epsilon$

First of all I noticed that for $1) M>n$ we have

$$
u_n([-M,M]) = 1
$$

and for $2) M \leq n$ we have

$$
u_n([-M,M]) = \frac Mn
$$

Not if we were to assume that $(u_n)$ was tight, then we could fix $\epsilon$ and choose $n = M+1$ then $u_n([-M,M]) = \frac Mn = \frac{M}{M+1} \not > 1- \epsilon$. The only we can be certain about the inequality is, if $M$ is arbitrarly large. But this would in my opinon contradict the tightness.

However I fell uncertain, because there is a follow up question wether $u_n$ converges weakly.

Comment: Your approach is right. You just need to choose $n=2M$ and $\epsilon=1/4$  to get the contradiction.